# Convert UTC time stamp in text to Excel date

Tags: excel, vba, date, time

I have dates in an Excel workbook with the format of

**Thu Feb 7 09:38:41 UTC+10 2019**

They are formatted as general/text.  Need to convert into an actual Excel date/time to sort.

Tried parsing and splitting but doesn't always works and is very clunky

Comment: What's your clunky failing parsing code like?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Answer (score 3):

Parsing seems the only sensible approach. Looks like a job for a regular expression though.

This function requires referencing the `VBScript_RegEp_55` type library:

```
Public Function ParseUtcDate(ByVal value As String, Optional ByVal utcOffset As Double = 0) As Date
    Const pattern As String = "(\w+) (\w+) (\d+) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) UTC((\+|\-)\d+) (\d\d\d\d)"
    With New RegExp
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        .pattern = pattern

        Dim mc As MatchCollection
        Set mc = .Execute(value)
    End With

    Dim m As Match
    Set m = mc(0)

    Dim monthNamePart As String
    monthNamePart = m.SubMatches(1)

    Dim dayOfMonthPart As String
    dayOfMonthPart = m.SubMatches(2)

    Dim timePart As String
    timePart = m.SubMatches(3)

    Dim utcOffsetPart As String
    utcOffsetPart = m.SubMatches(4)

    Dim yearPart As String
    yearPart = m.SubMatches(6)

    Dim dateParts As Variant
    dateParts = VBA.Array(monthNamePart, dayOfMonthPart, yearPart, timePart)

    Dim formattedDate As String
    formattedDate = VBA.Join(dateParts, " ")

    Dim offset As Double
    offset = CDbl(utcOffsetPart)

    Dim offsetHours As Double
    offsetHours = offset / 24

    Dim targetOffset As Double
    targetOffset = utcOffset / 24

    ParseUtcDate = CDate(formattedDate) - offsetHours + targetOffset

End Function
```

Usage:

```
?ParseUtcDate("Thu Feb 7 09:38:41 UTC+10 2019", 10)
 2/7/2019 9:38:41 AM

?ParseUtcDate("Thu Feb 7 09:38:41 UTC+10 2019")
 2/6/2019 11:38:41 PM

?ParseUtcDate("Thu Feb 7 09:38:41 UTC+10 2019", -5)
 2/6/2019 6:38:41 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, out of interest, if you have Excel 2016+ with the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can parse the segments with `FILTERXML` and then create a date/time string which Excel will interpret as a real date:

**Local time**

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s"),N(IF(1,{3,2,6}))))
+FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s[4]")
```

**UTC Time**

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s"),N(IF(1,{3,2,6}))))
+FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s[4]")
-SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s[5]"),"UTC","")/24
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any 'clunky' VBA code but I'e worked up a worksheet formula.

```
'for localized date/time
=SUM(DATEVALUE(TRIM(MID(REPLACE(A2, FIND(" ", A2, 9), 16, ", "), 4, LEN(A2)))),
     TIMEVALUE(MID(A2, FIND(" ", A2, 9)+1, 8)))
'for UTC date time
=SUM(DATEVALUE(TRIM(MID(REPLACE(A2, FIND(" ", A2, 9), 16, ", "), 4, LEN(A2)))),
     TIMEVALUE(MID(A2, FIND(" ", A2, 9)+1, 8)),
     -PRODUCT(VALUE(MID(A2, FIND("UTC", A2)+3, 3)), TIME(1, 0, 0)))
```

[image: usage example in Excel worksheet]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Impressive work! To be honest though, I find the readability/maintainability of the formula rather problematic. This is one of these cases where a UDF is in order IMO. That said, I made my own answer "community wiki", because the OP's question is, as it stands, off-topic as far as site rules are concerned (there's no apparent effort from the OP to solve the problem at hand).. but like you (I'm guessing), I thought this was an interesting problem to solve, so I posted anyway - but don't be surprised to see this question eventually get closed. Go answer some on-topic questions!

Comment: Sorry everyone, was in a bad car wreck and never got around to adding more detail.